# Problema con Header de Datagrid

Tags: vb.net, vba, datagrid, vb, datagridview

tengo el siguiente problema con un header de un datagrid, cambio la propiedad de Columnheadersdefaultcellstyle y se me alinean todas las cabeceras menos la ultima que es como si no tomara los cambios. En la imagen que adjunto la propiedad que tiene puesto Columnheadersdefaultcellstyle  es Middle Right y nose porque la 1er y 2da columna aparecen centradas y la tercera como digo, no hace nada, queda a la izquierda como si no formara parte del datagrid. Alguno me puede orientar sobre porque sucede esto?

[image: data]

Comment: puedes añadir el codigo donde creas el datagrid y donde colocas el formato al grid?

Comment: La informacion que se carga al datagrid la traigo con un adaptador desde una base de datos sql, por lo tanto lo unico que tengo de codigo relacionado con el dgv es eso, despues las modificaciones las hice desde la parte de propiedades. Tengo alguna manera de ver en codigo todas las propiedades del datagrid?

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione borrando el datagrid, creando uno nuevo y solamente modificar las propiedades Columnheadersdefaultcellstyle y DefaultCellStyle ambas en Middle Center y con eso funciono. Muchas gracias.